# How to distribute 3rd-party iOS apps made with Adobe Air in-house

Tags: ios, apache-flex, air, flash-builder, flex4.5

I have created an app for a client, using Adobe Air. I would like to distribute it under their in-house development program. I know there is an enterprise app-store but my client is not yet ready for that, so it has to be the in-house development program.

How should can I sign my app in FlashBuilder? Does my developer-id have to be registered as being a member of their in-house team? If so, what happens when another client wants to buy a different app from me?

Comment: Not a complete answer, just some instructions how to package enterprise distribution versions in the first place: http://fpstudios.com/2011/08/flash-enterprise-builds/

Comment: Thanks! A step in the right direction ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be simpler than I thought. I can just build it as an App Store release, and they can re-sign it with their certificate. It works.